# Android: Saving a canvas as a jpeg/png on SD card

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, jpeg

I have 2 images, one I get from my camera view, the other is upon the camera view.
I want to save the combination of these 2 images on my SD card. I think I have to zork zith canvas but I don't know how to save a canvas into jpeg i.e. write the data from canvas into a FileOutputStream

Here is my code

```
 output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
            ImageView view = (ImageView) gameactivity.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap2 = view.getDrawingCache();   
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
              catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(output.getAbsolutePath());
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, null, null);
// HERE I HAVE TO SAVE THE CANVAS INTO JPEG
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Could you please tell me if that is a good begining? and how to solve my problem, I don't find good answers on the similar post on stack (as I don't want to draw my canvas into view)